# Ionic 2 push notification not working in android version 4

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having a project with push notification(IONIC NATIVE PLUGIN). When running `ionic cordova run android` it works fine on android version 5. When the same running on android version 4 I'm getting the error

> UNFORTUNATELY,'App NAME' has stopped.

I don't know what to do. Any help?

Comment: What version of cordova you're using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
Use cordova version : 7.1.0

Use cordova plaform version : 6.3.0
```

To boost the performance in the app use crosswalk

The device version includes from android 4 to present

@Melchia Your answer is valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider downgrading your `cordova` version. Before creating an application you need to study you users (which version of Android they're using? Is it really worthy to make Android 4 version?...) You can't just install the latest version of cordova & hope everything is OK.

```
cordova-android Version     Supported Android API-Levels    Equivalent Android Version
6.X.X                                   16 - 25                   4.1 - 7.1.1
5.X.X                                   14 - 23                   4.0 - 6.0.1
4.1.X                                   14 - 22                   4.0 - 5.1
4.0.X                                   10 - 22                   2.3.3 - 5.1
3.7.X                                   10 - 21                   2.3.3 - 5.0.2
```

If you want to target Android 4.0 so install cordova 5.x.x. Run the following command `$ npm i -g cordova@5.4.1` Then run the following command `$ cordova platform add android@4.0`

Comment: I'm using cordova 8.0.0 everything works fine expect the push notification. I need to support from android 4.1 to the current latest android version.Which is the best stable cordova version.

Comment: Then you need Cordova 6.5.0

Comment: What about android platform version

Comment: Add the android 4.1 which will work in all platforms that come next.

Comment: Now its running on android version 4. But i cant install push notification plugin i'm getting this error "Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 6.5.0, failed version requirement: >=7.1.0"

Comment: Then you can't have that plug-in in android 4.1 devices!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164021/discussion-between-mohamed-ashiff-and-melchia).